# CSS - Alignment issues with image and text

Tags: css

Below is a screenshot indicating the manner I intend on placing an image and text above a list.

[my desired design](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1nMyjpx71zXQ2puSlVzVDliR2c/view?usp=sharing)

Below is my screenshot in terms of my misalignment problem.

[my alignment problems](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1nMyjpx71zXUlVVZUZ6Q2tsRmM/view?usp=sharing)

Below is the HTML for the image, the "FIRSTNAME SURNAME" text and the list below it:

```
    <section class="vertical_menu_bar_section">
    <div id="img_logged_in_user">
          <img src="http://static3.depositphotos.com/1005574/205/v/950/depositphotos_2053115-Smile-button.jpg" 
               height="128" width="128" align="left" /><p>FIRSTNAME SURNAME</p>
    </div>        

    <div id='vertical_menu'>
        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'><span>CALENDAR</span></a></li>
           <li><a href='#'><span>TOTALS</span></a></li>
           <li><a href='#'><span>OPTION 3</span></a></li>
           <li><a href='#'><span>OPTION 4</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<section>
```

Below is my CSS:

```
 /* Section - Vertical menu bar */
.vertical_menu_bar_section {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #FF0000;
    font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Tahoma, Sans-serif;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;    
}

#vertical_menu {
  background: #FF00CC;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Tahoma, Sans-serif;
  clear: both;
}

#vertical_menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#vertical_menu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#vertical_menu a {
  background: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#vertical_menu a:hover {
  background: #2580a2 url("/public/images/hover.gif") left center no-repeat;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

/* */
#img_logged_in_user {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: #2580a2;
}
```

Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please check if this is what you need**
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wv5shsz7/)

For the both Divs `.img_logged_in_user` and `.vertical_menu`I have introduced to a one common Div named as `.basic_div` The width in the Basic_div will affect the both and will be aligned

Also added a `<span>` so the user name wont get below the pic.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the image and name aligned you should set the `width` property of the wrapping element (which is `#img_logged_in_user`):

```css
#img_logged_in_user {
  width: 250px;
}
```

Then set the image `margin` to add a spacing between them:

```css
#img_logged_in_user > img {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

See live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/cdog/sbu24c45/.